# Migrating from WAMP to LAMP: File write errors from PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm porting a web system from Windows to Linux. I've solved most of the small issues, but this one is getting to me. I've got a text file which PHP writes logging information to. At the moment, PHP fails to open the file, citing 'permission denied'. As far as I'm aware:

- The directory and the file to be written have 770 permissions
- The directory and all the files below it are owned by the user 'web', and the group 'web'
- Apache is being run by user 'web'*

*I checked this by running:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

Any ideas? I can't figure this one out. I tested setting the directory and the file to 777 permissions, and I was able to write to file - obviously this isn't a viable workaround, this file is internal to the system and shouldn't be accessible externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is change to 777, as you said works, create a file and then look at the owner and group of the new file.